# Relation between roots of two quadratic equations

Tags: algebra-precalculus

We have two quadratic equations

$$\cases{3x^2+29x+56=0 &(1)\\
2y^2+15y+25=0 &(2)}$$

When solving each of them, I got

$$\cases{x=-7, -2.6666\\
y=-5,-2.5}$$

Can any one please clarify what is the relation between x and y?

Is it $x <y$ or $x \leq y$ or there is no relation between x and y ??

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Please reformat this using MathJax so that people can read the eqautions.

Comment: I was not able to find it... Is it there in playstore for android ?

Comment: A little remark; replace $2.666$ by $\frac{8}{3}$. Besides, I don't understand why you ask your question because it is evident that no order relationship can be seen between $x_1,x_2$ and $y_1,y_2$ (I have checked: your roots are exact)

Comment: I know there is no relation exists but stil i found from some one that there is x less than y relation. So just to confirm i asked here :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If these two equations hold simultaneously, then the four coordinates, namely $(-7,-5),(-7,-2.5),(-2.\dot{6},-5),(-2.\dot{6},-2.5)$, would be the only solutions to this system of equations.

Because the two quadratic equations are individually defined, so there is actually no relation between $x$ and $y$ aside from the four coordinates as mentioned. But $x$ and $y$ here can be different values, so you cannot say certainly $x\le y$ or $y\le x$.

Comment: Hi nick thanks for the reply... but i want to know the relation between x and y.... like is x greater than y or x greater than or equal to y or is there no relation between x and y ?